# Is it possible that A ∪ B ⊢ α ∧ ¬α, but there be no β such that A ⊢ β and B ⊢ ¬β?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, nonclassical-logic

In other words, is it possible in classical logic that two sets of sentences together ($\mathbf{A} \cup \mathbf{B}$) imply a contradictory proposition ($\alpha \wedge \neg \alpha$), but they fail to individually imply a sentence that contradicts a sentence of the other set (e.g. $\mathbf{A} \vdash \neg\beta$ and $\mathbf{B} \vdash \beta$)?

I'd like to know whether this is possible or not, the proof justifying the answer, and the name of the theorem, if it has one.

I would be even more grateful if I'm referred to a textbook explaining this in detail.

Answers in the framework of non classical logics (intutionistic, paraconsistent, relevant, etc.) are also welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Florian . From the Q in your link, we find that if $\neg Con (A\cup B)$ then there exist finite $S\subset A$ and finite $T\subset B$ such that $\land_{\sigma \in S}(\sigma) \iff \neg \land_{\tau \in T}(\tau)$ but this does not immediately tell us that $S$ (or $T$) may have exactly one member. I thought this would be easy. Now I'm puzzled.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet the linked question does construct a single sentence $\beta$ such that $T_1\vdash\neg\beta$ and $T_2\vdash\beta$, namely $\beta=\psi_1\land\cdots\land\psi_n$

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti . I understood the phrase "a sentence of the other set" in this Q to mean that he asks whether $(\exists b\in B\,(A\vdash \neg b))\lor (\exists a\in A\,(B\vdash \neg a)).$  The $\beta$ in your comment is a finite conjunction of members of $B$ but  not necessarily a member of $B$.